# Добавить блок в конец другого блока JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Как добавить блок в конец другого блока JQUERY, если в блоке, куда добавляется, может быть пустой, а может иметь уже элемент div. В случае, если имеется, нужно добавить перед ним.

Answer (score 2):

Проверяете количество div внутри блока и, если больше нуля, то **prepend()**, а если меньше - **append()**. В общем, [как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/W6dZS/1/).